# Sort sublists in a list, Python

Tags: python, sorting

I have the following list in Python upto n:

```
l = [[x_1,y_1,h_1,w_1], [x_2,y_2,h_2,w_2], ..., [x_n,y_n,h_n,w_n]]
```

And I need to sort it in descending order with respect to the sum of first and third elements in the sublists (x_i and h_i) and then get first n sublists.

I managed to do it by storing the sums in a new list, but is there an efficient way to sort it without creating the one?

EDIT: Sorry, this is a duplicate question indeed.

Comment: maybe with a real-life example (and actual numbers) your question would be clearer.

Comment: ok, so now your question is just "how to sort by criterion". Not very original... (and a duplicate)

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry for the duplicate!

Comment: at least you're admitting that it's a duplicate. Not everyone does that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to below link and see full detail how to sort in python

[sorting in python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting)

```
 a = sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[0] + x[2])
```

Answer (score 4):

You can sort a list using a specific key that you can define:

```
l.sort(key=lambda x: x[0] + x[2])
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That helps